# LoginButton of facebook

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-login

I am using LoginButton of facebook widget to login through facebook.

```
   mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this,Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
            }
        });
```

I am having two issues-

1.When I click on login button facebook login dialog opens two times.So after I logged in for first time after providing user email and password it shows another login dialog behind which i have to close.

2.After I logged in and move to next screen,if i come back to login screen it shows logout text in Login button which is ideal.But when i click on it it open both login and logout dialog box.Ideally it should open just logout dialog box.How should i prevent `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this,Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));`from being executed if user has already logged in.

Below is he code I am using

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private LoginButton mLoginButton;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
//        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
if(accessToken==null) {
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));

}
            }
        });
        mLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    }
                });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove setOnClickListener on loginButton, just RegisterCallBack on Login Button and it will handle it all, you don't need setOnClickListener for loginButton. It is called twice because you have set setOnClickListener and registerCalBack both.

```
CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fbLogin);
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_status,public_profile,user_friends,email,user_birthday"));
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new    FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onCancel() {

      }

     @Override
      public void onError(FacebookException error) {

      }
     });
```

You can check if the user is logged in or not by

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (accessToken != null) {
        }
        return accessToken != null;
```

Comment: Could you check on onError that it doesn't get called ?

Comment: It is gettingcalled.The issue is when I click on login button facebook login dialog opens two times.So after I logged in for first time after providing user email and password it shows another login dialog behind which i have to close.

Comment: And another issue is-How should i prevent LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this,Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));from being executed if user has already logged in and he clicked on logout button